# How to get title of all pages with WP Rest API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I need to get only title of all Pages of my wordpress site with WP Handbook API. I use this function in php to get all pages, but I need only the title. How do I do to manipolate the result data?

```
function getHomePage($link){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link . '/wp-json/wp/v2/pages');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $pagine = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $pagine;
}
```

In reality I need to get the content of only homepage. How do I do that?

Sorry for my bad english, but I'm Italian.